# give permissions to folders o365 powershell csom

Tags: document-library, powershell, permissions, folder

Have this code

```
function GetChildFolders($RootFolder)                       
{                        
    if($count -ne 1){                        
    $folderName=$folderName+'\'+$RootFolder.Name                        
    }                        
    $Context.Load($RootFolder)                        
    $Context.Load($RootFolder.Folders)                        
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()                        
    $count++                        

    if($folderName -eq $FolderRelativePath){                        

        $group = $Context.web.SiteGroups[$groupAD];                           
        $RootFolder.BreakRoleInheritance($false);                        
        $roleAssignment = New-Object microsoft.sharepoint.SPRoleAssignment($group);                        
        $roleDefinition = $Context.web.RoleDefinitions[$permission];                        
        $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);                           
        $spFolder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment);                               
        $spFolder.Update();                         
    }                        

    foreach($folder in $RootFolder.Folders)                        
    {                        

    GetChildFolders $folder                          

    }                        

}                        
GetChildFolders $List.RootFolder                        
$count = 1
```

This goes through all of the folders in my document library and if it matches a string (with a name of a folder in) it changes the permissions of that folder.

However I get an error saying

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] does not contain a method named
>   BreakRoleInheritance.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder` does not have property for `BreakRoleInheritance`

Update your code with below.

```
$RootFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$false)
```